# Looking for a smooth function with third derivative negative at minimum?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find a smooth function $f$ on the real line with compact support,
which has a unique minimum (at some $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$) and such that its third derivative there is negative, i.e. $f'''(x_{0})<0$.
I played around with exponential, ("cut offs" of) trigonometric functions etc.,
but I couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By *smooth*, do you mean *infinitely differentiable* at every point (including the boundaries of support)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=(x^2-x^3-1)\exp(1/(x^2-1))$ if $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\ge1$, and the point $x_0=0$.

Answer (score 2):

How about $-10+10x^2-x^3+x^4$, then "round off the corners" where it crosses the x axis to make it smooth and compact support?

Comment: The fourth derivative of this function is the constant 24 everywhere. How do you plan on "rounding the corners" to make it smooth? (I'm quite likely just being dense.)

Comment: @cardinal:  I would multiply it by a bump function that is zero outside $[-.8,.8],$ one over $[-.75,.75]$ and infinitely differentiable.  That will zero out the fourth derivative outside $[-.8,.8]$ as well.

Comment: I'll check that, as I was trying something similar.